# WM_QUERYENDSESSION is not working in IE8 activeX control

Tags: delphi, winapi, internet-explorer-8, activex, delphi-6

I have a ActiveX control written in Delphi 6 which handles WM_QUERYENDSESSION message to pop up a message box to let users to save changes before shutting down windows.
It works fine in IE6 / IE7 , but in IE8 the ActiveX control cannot receive WM_QUERYENDSESSION , how to solve this?

thanks

Comment: more details. the wm_queryendsession handler is in a top-levle dialog window. the OS is XP, it works fine in IE7 but not IE8

Comment: How do you know that WM_QUERYENDSESSION is not received? Did you check that by logging? Is it possible that you return 0 but that somehow gets ignored. How did you handle WM_ENDSESSION? Is it possible that another IE window gets WM_QUERYENDSESSION before your window and kills your window before it gets a chance to receive WM_QUERYENDSESSION?

Comment: only one IE window. and the message handler method will pop up a msg box (yes/no) , since the msg box was not displayed , so i assume the message is not received. and i do have a wm_queryendsession handler, not be called either.

Comment: There must be more than one window. IE has its window and you say you have a top-level window. And by window I mean something with an `HWND`.

Comment: yes , it has HWND and default winproc etc.

Comment: Yes what? My questions above stand.

Comment: anyway , it works in IE7 but not IE8 . so what's the difference between IE7 and IE8 for ActiveX windows message handling?

Comment: My attempt to help you was to steer you towards some debugging techniques. That's as much as I can manage.

Comment: is protected mode on for the security zone where the web page hosting your ActiveX is in?

Comment: @Sheng are you thinking that UIPI or some other sandboxing could be stopping the messages getting through